# Check if all matching elements match the criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example we have the next dataset:

```
balls = [
  {
    _id: 0,
    color: 'red',
    size: 10,
    available: true,
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    color: 'red',
    size: 15,
    available: false,
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    color: 'blue',
    size: 10,
    available: true,
  }
]
```

I want to run a query like:

```
balls.every({ color: 'red' }, { available: true }); // should return false
balls.update({ color: 'red', available: false }, { available: true }); // set unavailable red ball to true
balls.every({ color: 'red' }, { available: true }); // should return true
```

in a sort of `.every(query, condition)` type. If the documents returned from `query` are **all** matching the `condition`, return `true`, otherwise `false`.

Otherwise, I would have to get all matching documents, and then manually checking if all of them are available. I could save those steps with a solution like the above, and it would be less expensive.

Comment: is `balls` array field in document or all 3 objects are root document in collection?

Comment: `balls` is a collection/model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Every function to execute find query and check all available is true by every function,
- Or use aggregation query to return one document with all available status

```
async function _every(query, condition) {
  let result = await balls.find(query, { _id: 0, available: 1 }).lean();
  return (
    result.length > 0 &&
    result.every(e => e.available === condition.available)
  );
}

// OR

async function _every(query, condition) {
  let result = await balls.aggregate([
    { $match: query },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        available: { $push: "$available" }
      }
    }
  ]);
  return (
    result.length > 0 &&
    result[0].available.every(e => e === condition.available)
  );
}
```

- Update function to execute updateMany query:

```
async function _update(query, condition) {
  await balls.updateMany(query, { $set: condition });
}
```

You can execute your query like:

```
await _every({ color: 'red' }, { available: true }); 
await _update({ color: 'red', available: false }, { available: true }); 
await _every({ color: 'red' }, { available: true });
```

Comment: Updated the question, sorry I wasn't clear enough. Your solution doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can test and let me know its working as per your requirement.